# API call returns a variable with an "https" string that I need to convert into a URL to be used with AVPlayer

Tags: swift, rest, url, swiftui, avplayer

I'm new to swift and I'm making an API call, in my Model one of my struct returns a variable that's an "HTTP" string for audio, I'm trying to implement this in a class

In the view is asking me to provide a podcast parameter with sample data, I've tried providing sample data from the api but it doesn't seem to work.

```
class AudioManager : ObservableObject {
    let podcasts: Podcast
    
    init(podcasts: Podcast){
        self.podcasts = podcasts
       playAudio()
  }
    
    func playAudio(){
        let url : URL? = URL(string: podcasts.podcast)
        if url == url {
            let player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
            player.play()
        }
    }
```

```
struct PodcastView: View {
    
    @StateObject var audio = AudioManager(podcast: Podcast(id: Int, podcast: String, podcastName: String, unitID: Int))
    let podcasts: [Podcast]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(podcasts) { podcast in
            Text(podcast.podcastName)
        
                .onAppear{
                    audio.playAudio()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

If you could guide me in the right direction that would be great.
I would like to provide the URL (String: ) from the view rather than a class but I'm not sure on how to do it.

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing: The argument of `AudioManager(podcast:` must be something like `Podcast(id: 1, podcast: "https://example.com/podcast_foo", podcastName: "Foo", unitID: 1234)`. And `if url == url {` is wrong. Replace it with the previous line `if let url = URL(string: podcasts.podcast) { ...` and remove the exclamation mark in the next line. And please name ***sing***le elements in ***sing***ular form: `let podcast: Podcast`

Comment: I will name them in singular form thanks, I've tried replacing it with the line you mentioned but it won't let me, when I do that it ask exactly for the "https" string and I can't pass the variable

Comment: here's the API from where I'm making the call  "https://french-podcast.herokuapp.com/api/levels"

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is that you want to accept a parameter from your view and pass it onto your model to perform an action with it.

In your view you want

1. A state variable that tracks the changes in the variable.
2. A button to actually trigger the call at a specific point because SwiftUI view reload with every state change.

```
struct PodcastView: View {
    
    @StateObject var audio = AudioManager(podcast: Podcast(id: Int, podcast: String, podcastName: String, unitID: Int))
    @State var parameter: String = ""
    let podcasts: [Podcast]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(podcasts) { podcast in
    // This text field allows you to accept a typed paramter
            TextField($parameter)
            Text(podcast.podcastName)
        
   // This is the button that passes your parameter to your model. //Modify your function to accept this parameter
            Button("play the song") {
                   audio.playAudio(songParamter: parameter) 
        }
    }
}
```